# How can I lock the grid sort order in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, software

I have a selection of photos in Grid view, sorted by rating.  Now I want to go through and change ratings.  However, every time I change a photo's rating the grid re-sorts and moves to the changed photo's new location.  So I have to try to remember where it had been before to resume my re-rating process.

Is there a way to get Lightroom to lock the grid display order, and not re-sort until I tell it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "lock" the order by making a **Custom Sort order**. Once you have sorted the images you want using the rating, moving a thumbnail to an other place should enable the Custom Sort order. It's used [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2012/02/lr3-how-do-you-change-the-order-of-images-before-renaming.html) for renaming and an example is given [there](http://digitalphotobuzz.com/arranging-your-files-in-lightroom). You can also select it directly in the toolbar (you can see in the example I already have sorted the photos by ratings) :

[image: Lightroom Custom Order]

Another way to do it is to use a collection : Add to the Quick collection (might work with a "regular collection" but not tested) the photos you want, sort them by ratings, and then add to photos to a new empty "regular" collection (see [here](http://www.bashutterbug.com/2012/03/tweaking-a-custom-sort-order-in-lightroom-3/)).